# Update MySQL using HyperLink ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I store all data in MySQL and display it's some colums in gridview. Gridview's delete button works fine. I would like to edit datas so created HyperLink. it navigates another url and gets values from MySQL DB and sets textboxes, textareas. Everything is fine until this time but I try to edit values in new page it sets old values in DB. How i can solve this problem?

This my Main Page which has gridview and delete button, hyperlink KayitGoruntule.aspx;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KayitGoruntule.aspx.cs" Inherits="gop.KayitGoruntule" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .string {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
       <center><asp:Image ID="Banner" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/logo.png" Height="88px" Width="509px"></asp:Image></center>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMysqlData" runat="server"  CssClass="string"
             SelectedIndex="0" DataKeyNames="id"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDeleting="gvMysqlData_RowDeleting" Height="95px" Width="492px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">     
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:HyperLink ID="hpr1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("KayitAyrinti.aspx?id={0}",Eval("id")) %>'>
                             <img src="images/edit.png" />
                            </asp:HyperLink>
                              </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Navigated Url's page KayitAyrinti.aspx;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KayitAyrinti.aspx.cs" Inherits="gop.KayitAyrinti" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 217px;
        }

        .auto-style1 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 271px;
        }

 .degistir-button {
 background:#7ab752;
 margin:1px auto 0px;
 text-align:right;
 color:#FFF;
 /*border:none;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;*/
 -webkit-transition:background 0.5s;
 }
 .degistir-button:hover {
 background:#DC3F42 #81c356;
 }
 .kaydet-button {
 background:#7ab752;
 margin:auto;
 margin-right:4px;
 margin-left:60px;
 text-align:right;
 color:#FFF;
/* border:none;
 border-top-left-radius:40px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:40px;
 */
-webkit-transition:background 0.5s;

 }
 .kaydet-button:hover {
 background:#DC3F42 #81c356;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <center><asp:Image ID="Banner" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/logo.png" Height="88px" Width="509px"></asp:Image></center>
    <form id="register" runat="server">
            <br />
        <div>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" >
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad" runat="server" Text="Yetkili Adı Soyad :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>



            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul" runat="server" Text="Görüşme Yapılan Okul :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul" runat="server" Width="174px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Seyrantepe Şube 1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Seyrantepe Şube 2</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ayrintiveliAdSoyad" runat="server" Text="Veli Adı Soyadı :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiVeliAdiSoyadi_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                </td> 

            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_veliTel" runat="server" Text="Veli Telefon Numarası :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiVeliTel_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td> 

            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ikametAdres" runat="server" Text="İkamet Adresi :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                 <td class="auto-style2">
                     <textarea id="ayrintiIkametAdres_txt" rows="5" cols="26" runat="server"></textarea>
                 </td> 

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ogrenciAdSoyad" runat="server" Text="Öğrenci Adı Soyadı :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiOgrenciAdSoyad_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td> 

            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ogrenciTel" runat="server" Text="Öğrenci Telefon Numarası :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiOgrenciTel_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td> 

            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ilgilendigiBolum" runat="server" Text="İlgilendiği Bölüm :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum" runat="server" Width="174px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Hemşire Yardımcılığı</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Sağlık Bakım Teknisyenliği</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Anadolu Lisesi</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>            
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_verilenFiyat" runat="server" Text="Verilen Fiyat :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiVerilenFiyat_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td> 

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_gorusmeSonucu" runat="server" Text="Görüşme Sonucu :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ayrintiGorusmeSonucu_txt" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_gorusmeNotlari" runat="server" Text="Görüşme Notları :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>
                </td>   
                <td class="auto-style2"> 
                    <textarea id="ayrintiGorusmeNotlari_txt" rows="5" cols="26" runat="server"></textarea>
                </td> 

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Book Antiqua"></asp:Label>

                 </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">

                    <asp:button id="degistir" runat="server" text="Değiştir" class="degistir-button" OnClick="degistir_Click"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="kaydet" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" CssClass="kaydet-button" OnClick="kaydet_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This class is which shows values and try to update with degistir_Click,
KayitAyrinti.aspx.cs;

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace gop
{
    public partial class KayitAyrinti : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["kullanici"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write("Hoşgeldiniz..." + Session["kullanici"]);
                Response.Redirect("KayitAyrinti.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
               // Response.Write("Giriş Yapınız.");
            }
            string connectionString = "xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxx;";
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string[] keys = Request.QueryString.GetValues("id");
                String id = keys[0];
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id, yetkiliAdSoyad,gorusmeYapilanOkul,veliAdSoyad, veliTel, ikametAdres, ogrenciAdSoyad, ogrenciTel, ilgilendigiBolum,verilenFiyat,gorusmeSonucu,gorusmeNotlari from Kayitlar where id=" + id + "", cn);
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad_txt.Text = (reader["yetkiliAdSoyad"].ToString());
                            RadioButtonList_ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum.SelectedValue = (reader["gorusmeYapilanOkul"].ToString());
                            ayrintiVeliAdiSoyadi_txt.Text = (reader["veliAdSoyad"].ToString());
                            ayrintiVeliTel_txt.Text = (reader["veliTel"].ToString());
                            ayrintiIkametAdres_txt.InnerText = (reader["ikametAdres"].ToString());
                            ayrintiOgrenciAdSoyad_txt.Text= (reader["ogrenciAdSoyad"].ToString());
                            ayrintiOgrenciTel_txt.Text = (reader["ogrenciTel"].ToString());
                            RadioButtonList_ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum.SelectedValue= (reader["ilgilendigiBolum"].ToString());
                            ayrintiVerilenFiyat_txt.Text= (reader["verilenFiyat"].ToString());
                            ayrintiGorusmeSonucu_txt.Text= (reader["gorusmeSonucu"].ToString());
                            ayrintiGorusmeNotlari_txt.InnerText = (reader["gorusmeNotlari"].ToString());



                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }

        protected void degistir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;";
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string[] keys = Request.QueryString.GetValues("id");
                String id = keys[0];
                cn.Open();






               MySqlCommand komut = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Kayitlar SET yetkiliAdSoyad=@ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad, gorusmeYapilanOkul = @ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul,"+
                " veliAdSoyad = @ayrintiVeliAdSoyad ,veliTel = @ayrintiVeliTel,ikametAdres = @ayrintiIkametAdres ,ogrenciAdSoyad = @ayrintiOgrenciAdSoyad, " +
                "ogrenciTel=@ayrintiOgrenciTel,ilgilendigiBolum = @ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum,verilenFiyat=@ayrintiVerilenFiyat,gorusmeSonucu=@ayrintiGorusmeSonucu,gorusmeNotlari=@ayrintiGorusmeNotlari", cn);

                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad", ayrintiYetkiliAdSoyad_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul", RadioButtonList_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedValue);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiVeliAdSoyad", ayrintiVeliAdiSoyadi_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiVeliTel", ayrintiVeliTel_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiIkametAdres", ayrintiIkametAdres_txt.InnerText);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiOgrenciAdSoyad", ayrintiOgrenciAdSoyad_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiOgrenciTel", ayrintiOgrenciTel_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum", RadioButtonList_ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum.SelectedValue);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiVerilenFiyat", ayrintiVerilenFiyat_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiGorusmeSonucu", ayrintiGorusmeSonucu_txt.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayrintiGorusmeNotlari", ayrintiGorusmeNotlari_txt.InnerText);

                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Redirect("KayitGoruntule.aspx");
                komut.Dispose();




            }
        }



        protected void kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Upon initial review, it looks like your UPDATE statement has no WHERE clause to restrict affected records to only that one with the specified ID; as a result, ALL of your records would seemingly be updated with the values from the various text boxes....

Comment: I forgot to add it here but it has where clause in real code. Answer is works fine which is down. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textboxes on your form are being populated with their database defaults in the `Page_Load` event. This is fine the first time through; however, when you click your 'degistir' button, a "postback" occurs, and `Page_Load` fires *again* and *repopulates* those defaults, losing whatever changes were submitted. Keep in mind that `Page_Load` fires *before* any control click events.

To fix this, you need to check for `IsPostback` in `Page_Load` to prevent your loader from firing on the update. If `IsPostback` is true, inhibit the load of the defaults from your database. This, in turn, should allow the update to occur with the updated data provided on your form. Something along these lines:

```
        // code snipped...
        if (Session["kullanici"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write("Hoşgeldiniz..." + Session["kullanici"]);
            Response.Redirect("KayitAyrinti.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
           // Response.Write("Giriş Yapınız.");
        }
        if (!IsPostback)  // <-- Add this check
        {
            string connectionString = "xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxx;";
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string[] keys = Request.QueryString.GetValues("id");
                /// rest of code snipped
```

Also, be sure to modify your UPDATE statement to include a WHERE clause that limits the UPDATE to only that record with the desired ID. As it is, ALL your records will be updated!